# regular expression search - find original class/struct name of a typedef'd value

Tags: regex

I'm created an hpp file and I need to forward declare classes as I cannot assume they are included at the time.

I have a typedef'd class, and I want to do a find in files to find the line where this is typedef'd so I can get the original class or struct name.

How can I do this?  I want to search for:
typedef "AnythingInBetween" name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
^\s*typedef\s+[a-z:<>.]+\s+thename
```

This will work for cases where it's a typedef to a single name which matches 'thename' and everything occurs on a single line.  This isn't fully respective of the C++ grammar for typedefs (a regex simply can't be) but will catch the 90% case

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of regex do you need it in? I'm gonna guess this is what you need?

```
typedef\s"(.*?)"\sname
```

`\s"(.*?)"\s` means match a space char followed by a double quote then anything until the next double quote followed by a space